# analogy to scipy.interpolate.griddata?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolate a given 3D point cloud:

I had a look at scipy.interpolate.griddata and the result is exactly what I need, but as I understand, I need to input "griddata" which means something like `x = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]`.

But my given 3D point cloud don't has this grid-look - The x,y-values don't behave like a grid - anyway there is only a single z-value for each x,y-value.*

So is there an alternative to scipy.interpolate.griddata for my not-in-a-grid-point-cloud?

*edit:
"no grid look" means my input looks like this:

```
x = [0,4,17]
y = [-7,25,116]
z = [50,112,47]
```

Comment: The name is misleading: `griddata` takes unstructured data, such as yours, and interpolates it. I guess the name comes from it typically being used to resample a cloud of points into a proper grid. Read the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), the worked out example is quite revealing of how to go about using it. If you are going to interpoalte over more than a single set of points, you should consider using the interpoaltor objects refered to in the docs instead: you don't want to be building the interpolator more than once.

Comment: I have a question in addition (or should I start a new thread for it?) Is it possible to "cut" a certain z-value out of this interpolation? Means, I want to enter a z-value and want to get back some kind of function which describes the "casing" at that z-value - or just returns me the area inside that casing.

Comment: What do you mean with "casing"? I don't think I uderstand what you mean... In any case, the proper thing to do is to ask a new question: both for making the answer easy to find for others, and to get you more attention from other folks.

Comment: OK I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499108/scipy-interpolate-griddata-cut-z-value-and-get-area-inside-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a function I use for this kind of stuff:

```
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid

def grid(x, y, z, resX=100, resY=100):
    "Convert 3 column data to matplotlib grid"
    xi = linspace(min(x), max(x), resX)
    yi = linspace(min(y), max(y), resY)
    Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
    X, Y = meshgrid(xi, yi)
    return X, Y, Z
```

Then use it like this:

```
  X, Y, Z = grid(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scipy has documentation with a specific example of how to use scipy.interpolate.griddata and they explain exactly what you are asking for. Look here:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

In short, you do this the get the "grid data":

```
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
```

This would make a 100x200 grid which ranges from 0 to 1 in both x- and y-direction.

```
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-10:10:51j, 0:2:20j]
```

This would make a 51x20 grid which ranges from -10 to 10 in x-direction and 0 to 2 in y-direction.

Now you have to correct input for scipy.interpolate.griddata.