# scipy.interpolate.griddata: cut z-value and get area inside it

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Regarding to this: [analogy to scipy.interpolate.griddata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496783/analogy-to-scipy-interpolate-griddata)
I have an additional question:
My output looks like this:[image]

It's a pyramid with noise (and without ground side).
Is there a possibility in scipy.interpolate.griddata to enter/choose a certain z-value so that all points which **aren't** equal this z-values gets deleted? In my example: e.g. I enter a high z-value -> only the points with a certain red-value (= z-value) should stay alive and show me a non-filled, noised, red triangle. The goal is to get the area inside this noised triangle.

edit: 
tldr: as I just learned, it's an **isoline** what I am looking for and the area inside it.

edit2:
So I found out that from this example http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html "grid_z1.T" returns me an array with all the z-values. In a loop I could eliminate all values which does not equal a certain z-value -> I got my isoline. Problem is, that it's not rellay an iso**line** but a grid with some iso-values. It's quite ok, but maybe there is a better solutions?
Are there some other methods then grid_z.T which could fit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that special case I could solve it an easy way:
Instead of eliminating all values which doesn't equal a certain z-value, I just eliminated all values which ar **above** a certain z-value:

```
if grid_z1.T[i][j] > z0 or math.isnan(grid_z1.T[i][j]):
    grid_z1.T[i][j] = np.nan
```

Because I defined gridsize by myself I easily can calculate area by multiply gridsize with count of points.

OT: Sorry for replying that late - I've been 1 week in hospital.

Answer (score 1):

This is best done before you transform the data to grid form:

```
>>> x = [0,4,17]
>>> y = [-7,25,116]
>>> z = [50,112,47]

>> data = np.column_stack([x, y, z])
array([[  0,  -7,  50],
       [  4,  25, 112], # <<----------------  Keep this
       [ 17, 116,  47]])
>>> data = data[data[:,2] == 112]  # points with z==112
array([[  4,  25, 112]])
```

then you can transform the data for plotting using griddata or for example the function given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499760/1330293):

```
X, Y, Z = grid(data[0], data[1], data[2])
```

Comment: If I understand you right, then I will get a problem: I only have several points of the pyramid, but above you see all points because I did an interpolation. If I first cut out certain points and do interpolation only for them, the interpolation wouldn't be accurate enough for me. I need to do interpolation with all given points because, regarding to your/my example, points with higher and lower z-values have an effect on the triangle-look at z=-112.